# How to delete data from Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I tried deleting the entities from Core Data the have two entities named
1. RootCategory
2. ChildCategory

and RootCategory may have some ChildCategory as it's parent, and ChildCategory may have some RootCategory as it's parent, While trying to delete using the following:

```
-(void)deleteCategory:(NSInteger)caterogyId
{
    NSManagedObjectModel *dataModel = [self dataModel];

    //    NLog(@"%@", TO_JSON(@"results", results, nil));
    RootCategory *rootCategory = (RootCategory *) [dataModel fetchOne:CD_RootCategory
                                                                  predicate:@"categoryId == %d and parentChildCategory
 == nil", categoryId];
    if ( rootCategory.childCategorys.count != 0 ) {
        // delete everything from under the leaves in this category

        for ( ChildCategory *childCategory in rootCategory.childCategorys ) {
            for ( RootCategory *rootCategory in childCategory.childRootCategory )
                [dataModel deleteEntity:rootCategory];

        }
    }
}
```

The corresponding records are not deleting from the Core Data DB.
Why this happens, I call this deleteEntity from two ways, 
It works perfect on one set of data on one view, and trying to delete another set of data from another view but it's not deleting.

Can anyone resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Two dumb questions:

1. You are sure it's entering your loop?
2. You executed a save on the context after all the deletes?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to delete managed objects and not entities (which are more like classes or "templates" for objects in Core Data).

For this, you have to use the `deleteObject:` method of your `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Comment: If you save the context though, it is essentially the same thing.

Comment: No, it's definitely not the same thing and it has nothing to do with saving the context.

Comment: Can you explain the difference then? Because I would really like to know.